# Schedule export data for a particular user

Tags: data-export

How can we schedule export data for a particular user only. So that when export data us ready it should be emailed to that user only. Do we have any option to customize it. Bec when I set the schedule export data it does't ask for any user, profile, role, group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dataloader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) for this. That way you can select on whatever criteria you like.

In order to schedule dataloader, you can use the Command Line Interface (CLI) in combination with the scheduler of your OS, e.a. Windows Scheduler. Create a batch file that will in turn call the Data Loader.

Use the Dataloader config file to automatically login.

More info on Dataloader CLI [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line).

Comment: Hi Anu, did you manage to get this to work?